# Real time video player to embed in an Android app

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, exoplayer

I need a library that supports real time video streaming from an RTSP connection to embed in an Android application I've built. It must have a really low latency (1-2s should be fine). I've already tried with a simple VideoView. It works but it has a HUGE latency (more than 10s) because its buffer size cannot be lowered.

Is there any good and reliable solution?
I would prefer not to build my own player from scratch...

ExoPlayer doesn't seem to support RTSP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39717848/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/q/47860410/115145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved using a modified version of Exoplayer (RTSP Exoplayer GitHub pull request). The buffer size can be edited, so I think it's the best choice for this use case.
It works flawlessly!

Comment: how to solve this please provide me the solutions and sours or guide